# Get an Instance using Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject

How can I get a single instance using Ninject? Here's my Service Module:

```
public class ServicesModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Kernel.Bind<IDocumentServiceApi>().To<DocumentServiceApi>().InRequestScope();
        Kernel.Bind<IConfigurationService>().To<ConfigurationService>().InRequestScope();
        Kernel.Bind<IReportGenerationProcessor>().To<ReportGenerationProcessor>().InRequestScope();
    }
}
```

I need an instance of `IReportGenerationProcessor` to fire off a message I am receiving from an Azure Service Bus Queue.

I've seen a lot of different ways, but none have worked for me. I constantly get the error :`Object instance not set to an instance of an object`.

```
//I do instantiate this class using new WebJobBase();
public class WebJobBase
    {
        public void ProcessMessage(BrokeredMessage message)
        {
                // Just need an instance of IReportGenerationProcessor here
                var _processor = new ReportGenerationProcessor();
                _processor.ProcessMessage(message);
        }
    }
```

Here's my `IReportGenerationProcessor` implementation:

```
    public interface IReportGenerationProcessor
    {
        DocumentMetaData ProcessMessage(BrokeredMessage message);
    }
    public class ReportGenerationProcessor : IReportGenerationProcessor
    {
        // Go figure these don't work either
        [Inject]
        public IConfigurationService _config { get; set; }
        [Inject]
        public IDocumentServiceApi _docService { get; set; }

        public DocumentMetaData ProcessMessage(BrokeredMessage message)
        {
            var report = message.GetBody<ReportMetaData>();

            //Do some stuff
            return new DocumentMetaData(); // just a place holder
        }
    }
```

If I can provide more information, please let me know. I'm not too knowledgeable on Ninject.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, so the documentation kind of hinted at this, but they didn't use an Interface and registered `.ToSelf()`.

Basically I needed to instantiate a new `StandardKernel` with my `ServicesModule` from above, and call the `.Get<>();` method for my registered Interface.

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new ServicesModule());
var processor = kernel.Get<IReportGenerationProcessor>();
processor.ProcessMessage(message);
```

Comment: You can also do `kernel.Load<ServicesModule>()` instead of passing all the modules to the kernel constructor.

Comment: Is that like lazy loading or something? And please feel free to edit my answer if you know of other ways!

Comment: Not really, "lazy" refers to "as needed", so let's say you had a `ServiceModule` with a binding for `IService`. Now if `ServiceModule` is only loaded once an `IService` is requested, we would call this lazy.
`kernel.Load<TModule>()` loads the module immediately. The only difference is that you can, for example, look for modules by reflection (or plugin infrastructure) and then dynamically load them - even after creation of the kernel. Your approach is totally ok.

Comment: Oh, that would be interesting (and possibly costly?)..I'm not much of a DI expert so even getting these 2 lines of code was a struggle, sadly.

Comment: Well i would not recommend to use reflection unless there's a good reason to do so ;-). Anyway, another remark which is more useful: You should, whenever possible, use constructor-injection instead of propery injection. Meaning your `ReportGenerationProcessor` should have a constructor `public ReportGenerationProcessor(IConfigurationService configurationService, IDocumentServiceApi documentServiceAp)` - to ensure the object is always initialized correctly (=> prefer exception being thrown early = at creation of object - rather than later when trying to access a dependency)

Comment: Get extension method does not exist anymore , for some reason